# How to continue python script loop even though IOError?

Tags: python, exception, twitter

I have a program which request info from the twitter API, and from time to time I get an error:

```
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

I want to know how can I keep my script running (looping). I know that this has something to do with:

```
try:

except IOError:
```

but I can not figure it out.

Answer (score 6):

The simpler structure is like this:

```
my_while_or_for_loop:
    some_code_here_maybe
    try:
        my_code_or_function_that_sometimes_fails()
    except IOError:
        pass   # or some code to clean things that went wrong or to log the failure
    some_more_code_here_maybe
```

You want to [read the docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

The full construction can be more complex and includes `try/except/else/finally`.
[From an example in docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions):

```
>>> def divide(x, y):
...     try:
...         result = x / y
...     except ZeroDivisionError:
...         print "division by zero!"
...     else:
...         print "result is", result
...     finally:
...         print "executing finally clause"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is is documentationabout [exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html)...

Simply, if a code block have possibility to cause some known errors (like input output error) in some conditions, you define an `try-except`block to handle such errors. That will make your script keep runnung and let you execute diffrent code blocks according to diffrent error status.... Like:

```
try:
    <do something>
except IOError:
    <an input-output error occured, do this...>
except ValueError:
    <we got something diffrent then we expected, do something diffrent>
except LookupError:
    pass # we do not need to handle this one, so just kkeep going...
except: 
    <some diffrent error occured, do somethnig more diffrent>
```

If you simply do nothing and continue, you can use `pass`, like:

```
try:
    <do something>
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

The part you're missing is `pass`. That is a simple *no-op* expression, which exists because Python can have no empty blocks.

#### The longer explanation:

What you need to do is to catch the IOError exception being thrown, and ignore it (possibly logging it and such) using `pass`.

To do that you need to wrap the code that can fail in a `try` and `except` block, like this:

```
try:
    <code that can fail>
except IOError:
    pass
```

What this does is explicitly ignore IOErrors, while not ignoring others. If you want to ignore all exceptions, simply remove the `IOError` part so the line says `except:`.

You should really read the Python tutorial, specifically the section about [error handling](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try:
    <do something - you code here>
except IOError: pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Or why not:

```
with ignored(IOError):
    <code that can fail>
```